# Animate / update value of tube geometry path points

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a `TubeGeometry` by passing in a `SplineCurve3` / `CatmullRomCurve3` path as a parameter.

I am trying to update the position of each of the path's points with `geometry.parameters.path.points[1].y += 0.01;` under `requestAnimationFrame`.

The values itself updates on console.log but the points dont move. How can i do this?

By the way, i'm not looking to move 'vertices' but rather the points of the path that shape how the tube is rendered.

```js
var camera, scene, light, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();


function init() {


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

 // default bg canvas color //
 renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
 //  use device aspect ratio //
 // renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 // set size of canvas within window //
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


 // create camera //
 // params = field of view, aspect ratio, clipping of near objects, clipping of far objs 
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
 camera.position.z = 100;
 // create scene 
 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 // create ambient lighting, params -> color, intensity
 light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
 // add light to scene
 scene.add(light)
 

 // create line, with params as x,y,z 
 var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
     new THREE.Vector3( -60, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -50, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -40, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -30, -10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -20, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -10, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 10, -10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 20, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 30, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 40, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 50, -10, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 60, 0, 0 )
 ]);

 curve.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


 for (i = 0; i < curve.points.length; i++) { 

  // this will get a number between 1 and 10;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
  num *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;

     curve.points[i].y = num;
     // console.log(curve.points[i].y);
 }

 geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve, 1000, 0.2, 8, false);
 geometry.dynamic = true;


 /* standard material */
 material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
  color: 0xff0000
 });

 // create mesh
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 // set positon of line 
 mesh.position.set(0,0,-10);


 // add to scene 
 scene.add(mesh);

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);



} /* end init */



function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

//console.log(geometry.parameters.path.points);


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}


function render() {

 // mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
 // mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

 geometry.parameters.path.points[1].y += 0.01;
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
 //console.log(geometry.parameters.path.points[1].y)
 


 /* render scene and camera */
 renderer.render(scene,camera);

}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it working using `TubeGeometry`, but I did with `TubeBufferGeometry`. Luckily, there isn't much to change, because both use the curve path to define the mesh vertices. You're free to try to replicate this with `TubeGeometry` instead.

The main problem you're seeing though is that `Tube(Buffer)Geometry` BUILDS geometry, rather than IS geometry, and that's where the convenience ends. Updating the path does not trigger the geometry to rebuild. Instead, if you update your path, you must recreate the `Tube(Buffer)Geometry`.

In the code below, all I did was swap `TubeBufferGeometry` in place of `TubeGeometry`, changed `geometry.verticesNeedUpdated` to `geometry.needsUpdate` (this is how `BufferGeometry` handles updates), and added the line which re-builds the tube:

```
geometry.copy(new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(geometry.parameters.path, 1000, 0.2, 8, false));
```

```js
var camera, scene, light, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();


function init() {


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

 // default bg canvas color //
 renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
 //  use device aspect ratio //
 // renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 // set size of canvas within window //
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


 // create camera //
 // params = field of view, aspect ratio, clipping of near objects, clipping of far objs 
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
 camera.position.z = 100;
 // create scene 
 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 // create ambient lighting, params -> color, intensity
 light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5)
 // add light to scene
 scene.add(light)
 

 // create line, with params as x,y,z 
 var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
     new THREE.Vector3( -60, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -50, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -40, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -30, -10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -20, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( -10, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 10, -10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 20, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 30, 10, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 40, 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector3( 50, -10, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 60, 0, 0 )
 ]);

 curve.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


 for (i = 0; i < curve.points.length; i++) { 

  // this will get a number between 1 and 10;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
  num *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;

     curve.points[i].y = num;
     // console.log(curve.points[i].y);
 }

 geometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(curve, 1000, 0.2, 8, false);
 geometry.dynamic = true;


 /* standard material */
 material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
  color: 0xff0000
 });

 // create mesh
 mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 // set positon of line 
 mesh.position.set(0,0,-10);


 // add to scene 
 scene.add(mesh);

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);



} /* end init */



function onWindowResize() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

//console.log(geometry.parameters.path.points);


function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}


function render() {

 // mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
 // mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

 geometry.parameters.path.points[3].y += 0.01;
  geometry.copy(new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(geometry.parameters.path, 1000, 0.2, 8, false));
  geometry.needsUpdate = true;
 //console.log(geometry.parameters.path.points[1].y)
 


 /* render scene and camera */
 renderer.render(scene,camera);

}
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @wsgg I'm glad it worked for you. Just keep in mind that this is not all that memory-friendly. If you profile the page, you'll see a saw-tooth pattern as the tube is recreated over and over, and garbage collection cleans up after it. A better way would be to externalize the function that triggers building the tube, allowing you to replace the vertices with new ones. It's still not optimal, but it would prevent the `new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry` in the render loop.